# how to remove all permissions in a database?

Tags: sql-server, replication, permissions, restore, scripting

every time I need to either [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/72854/22336) a database or [reinitialize a replication publication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/209443/22336) I first (on the restored to be or subscription database) I script all the [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125158/22336), [triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204238/22336), [indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20355/22336), [synonyms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191880/22336), sometimes [statistics](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/235517/22336)

then I do the restore or (apply the snapshot) and then 
re-apply my saved scripts on the restored database.

I have some LIVE servers where the [db_denydatawriter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/218563/22336) have been used profusely and although I have all the permissions as they used to be, because the `db_denydatawriter` comes with the restore (because it was in live) the new restored database has it now.

and it causes problems.

so much so that now I have this script (uses [sp_foreachdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149460/22336)) just to remove that in test:

```
     declare @db_list NVARCHAR(MAX)


     SELECT @db_list  = STUFF((
                                SELECT ', ' + name FROM sys.databases
                                WHERE name NOT IN ('DBA','TABLEBACKUPS','MASTER','MSDB','MODEL','TEMPDB','distribution')
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

     SELECT [@db_list]  =@db_list 

     exec sp_foreachdb @database_list = @db_list
                     ,@exclude_list = 'dba,tablebackups,master,msdb,model,tempdb'
                     ,@command='use ?;begin try EXEC sp_droprolemember @rolename = [db_denydatawriter], @membername = [mycompany\Developers] end try begin catch end catch '
```

question:

How can I delete all the permissions in the newly restored database `before` I apply my scripts containing the permissions before the restore?

In other words, what would be the easiest way to remove all existing permissions (after the restore) before I re-apply the former permissions?

Comment: Can you simply remove all the database principals?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sp_dbpermissions <db_name>`.

It will give both grant and revoke scripts.

you can download the script by Kenneth Fisher from [his blog](https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/).

Comment: I also use that script, and for automated needs it was a great inspiration for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should help drop all users after restore.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = ''

select @sql = @sql + '
print ''Dropping ' + name + '''drop user ' + name + ''
from dbo.sysusers
where name not in ('dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys', 'public') and LEFT(name, 3) <> 'db_'
order by name

--print @sql
execute (@sql)
```